# How to get the system proxy settings in Linux using c

Tags: c++, c, linux

How to read the system proxy setting values in linux using c or c++

Comment: The `http_proxy` environment variable has the proxy being used.

Comment: i used the following lines to get proxy settings
 char *command= (char*)"gconftool-2 -R /system/http_proxy";
  FILE *fpipe = (FILE*)popen(command,"r");
  char line[256];
  while ( fgets( line, sizeof(line), fpipe))
  {
  
  
    printf("%s", line);
  }
  pclose(fpipe);

Answer (score 4):

you are looking for this function `getenv ("http_proxy")`

Comment: getenv("http_proxy") returns null in ubuntu . is there any other options.

Comment: getenv function will return NULL if there is no match for any env variable set. So try env command on the shell manually and try to find if the ubuntu system you are talking about have http_proxy set or not

Answer (score 1):

System proxy settings are generally stored in environment variables like HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY etc.

'C' allows us to read enrolment variables via adding an extra argument `envp` to the main() function as shown.

```
    int main (int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
    {
      char *http_proxy, *https_proxy;
      http_proxy = getenv("HTTP_PROXY");
      https_proxy = getenv("HTTPS_PROXY");
      printf ("Proxy settings :: %s on %s.\n", http_proxy, https_proxy);
      return 0;
    }
```

This should do the trick depending on what variables you would want to process.

Comment: This will most likly print the value for `https_proxy` twice, as `getenv()` may return a reference to static memory which will be reused and therefore overwritten on the second call.

Comment: getenv("HTTP_PROXY"); returns null in ubuntu .

Answer (score 0):

Most Linux distributions that I've seen do not have the notion of a "system proxy". The desktop environments that run on top of Linux (KDE, Gnome, etc....) generally have configuration options to set up a proxy, which most applications written for that desktop will then have access to, but how to look that up in code will be different depending on which environment you're running. Also, running e.g. KDE apps under Gnome or vice versa may not get the same results, unless both have been configured properly. Because of this and a number of other things, many individual applications have their own way to set proxies. One of those possible ways, that works for some applications is the environment variables mentioned in other answers (other possibilities being various configuration files, or connecting to one of the configuration services like gconf). If you're writing a new app and just want to be able to set and use a proxy in that app, this approach is probably one of the simplest.